# How to set period for vertical ticks?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3 library version 5.7.0. I make simple graph. Vertical axis have several ticks? these ticks have period 5000.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/xng2weko/12/)

But i need period 10000. Please help me.

js code:

```
xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100000])
  .range([paddingYaxis, w - padding]);

yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => +d['price'] + yPeriod)])
  .range([h - padding, tickSize]);

xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickSizeInner(0)
  .tickSizeOuter(tickSize)
  .tickPadding(tickPadding);

yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickSizeInner(-(w - paddingYaxis - tickSize * 2))
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickPadding(tickPadding)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(' '));
```

Comment: you can use `.ticks(5)` or use `.tickValues([0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide a generic solution for various ranges (not just up to 50000). The ticks function allows you to choose a certain amount of ticks, dividing by the period size, gives us the wanted result.

```
yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickSizeInner(-(w - paddingYaxis - tickSize * 2))
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickPadding(tickPadding)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(' '))
  .ticks(d3.max(data, d => +d['price'] + yPeriod) / 10000);
```